# Рандомная генерация префабов в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хотел бы, чтобы префабы спавнились на расстоянии друг от друга, и чтобы они не залезали друг на друга. Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomGenerate : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform spawnPos;
[SerializeField] Vector2 range;
[SerializeField] GameObject platform;
public int SpawnCount;
public int Generated = 0;
public float minRange, maxRange;

// Start is called before the first frame update

IEnumerator Spawn()
{
    int rand = Random.Range(0, 3);
    if (rand == 0)
    {
        minRange += 10f;
        maxRange += 15f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        Vector2 pos = spawnPos.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(minRange, maxRange), Random.Range(0, 3));
        Instantiate(platform, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        
    }
    if (Generated <= 24)
    {
        Repeat();
    }
   
}
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Spawn());
}
void Repeat()
{
    StartCoroutine(Spawn());
    Generated++;
}
```

}

Comment: Думаю буду капитаном очевидностью, если скажу, что для этой хотелки, результат рандомизации нужно проверять на колизию с ранее созданными объектами. Но ты даже не пытаешся...

Comment: Да, до этого я успел догадаться, но я не понимаю что и как лучше использовать: OnCollisionEnter, CastBox или что-то другое

Comment: Способов воз и телега. Можно хоть записать размеры в Vector2 и использова, позицию, размер, плюс, минус, больше, меньше, примитивную математику начальной школы вообшем не прибигая к вычислениям линейной алгибры физики движка.

Comment: Что кстати я и делаю, но всё равно объекты лепятся друг на друга

Comment: Значит... капитан очевидность: ты что-то делал не так. Но нам откуда знать что?

Comment: Так а для чего я обращаюсь на форум? Вот именно, чтобы узнать что я сделал не так, и что применить лучше

Answer (score 1):

1. Генерируешь случайную позицию.
2. Генерируешь Bounds на основе этой позиции и Bounds коллайдера или МешРендерера платформы.
3. Через Physics.CheckBox проверяешь пересекается ли этот Bounds с другими на сцене. Если да - спаунишь объект, если нет - повторяешь с п. 1.

Имей в виду, если platform это префаб, а не объект на сцене, то у него изначально будут Bounds нулевого размера, пока он на сцене не появится.

Comment: Я решил просто генерировать рандомный Y. Вроде объектов, которые залезают друг на друга стало меньше. Спасибо за потраченное время)